# Is there any way to simplify $\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{x}{i} \binom{y}{i + 1}$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

All these numbers are naturals and $$n \leq x\,,\quad\left(n + 1\right) \leq y$$

Answer (score 3):

A simple sub-case ($n\geq\max(x,y-1)$) can be solved through Vandermonde's identity.

If you write your sum as
$$ \sum_{i\geq 0}\binom{x}{x-i}\binom{y}{i+1} $$
you may easily recognize a convolution, equal to the coefficient of $z^{x+1}$ in the product between $(1+z)^x$ and $(1+z)^y$. And the coefficient of $z^{x+1}$ in $(1+z)^{x+y}$ is simply:
$$ \binom{x+y}{x+1} = \binom{x+y}{y-1}$$

Comment: Are you sure ?. Please, check the result with $Mathematica$. It yields some $\texttt{hypergeometric function}$ and $\texttt{binomials}\ldots$

Comment: I'm sorry, I understood that the coefficient of $z^{x+1}$ in $(1+z)^{x+y}$ is 
$$ \binom{x+y}{x+1}$$. But not why this is equal to the answer of the question. Thanks

Comment: I was simply referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity

Comment: @FelixMarin: oh, well, you are right, I actually just solved the case $n\geq\max(x,y-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 0}^{n}{x \choose i}{y \choose i + 1} & =
\bracks{z^{n}}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}z^{\ell}\bracks{\sum_{i = 0}^{\ell}{x \choose i}{y \choose i + 1}} =
\bracks{z^{n}}\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}{x \choose i}{y \choose i + 1}
\sum_{\ell = i}^{\infty}z^{\ell}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{z^{n}}\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}{x \choose i}{y \choose i + 1}
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}z^{\ell + i} =
\bracks{z^{n}}\bracks{\pars{1 - z}^{-1}\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}{x \choose i}
{y \choose y - i - 1}z^{i}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{n}}\bracks{\pars{1 - z}^{-1}\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}{x \choose i}z^{i}
\bracks{w^{y - i - 1}}\pars{1 + w}^{y}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{n}}\braces{\pars{1 - z}^{-1}\bracks{w^{y - 1}}
\bracks{\pars{1 + w}^{y}\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}{x \choose i}\pars{zw}^{i}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{n}}\braces{\vphantom{\LARGE A}\pars{1 - z}^{-1}\bracks{w^{y - 1}}
\bracks{\vphantom{\Large A}\pars{1 + w}^{y}\pars{1 + zw}^{x}}}
\\[5mm] = &
{1 \over \pars{y - 1}!}\bracks{z^{n}}\braces{\pars{1 - z}^{-1}
\left.\,\partiald[\,y - 1]{}{w}\bracks{\pars{1 + w}^{y}\pars{1 + zw}^{x}}
\right\vert_{\ w\ =\ 0}}
\end{align}

> The 'possible answer' still like cumbersome !!!.